# PIvot R dataframe and Convert to List

Tags: r, list, dataframe

How do I pivot an R dataframe to a list of specific values where the table can have lookups done by name?

```
   id                  ts sensorId reading            sensor       units
1 651 2017-02-05 19:55:45        1    -127 WaterThermometer     Celsius
2 652 2017-02-05 19:55:46        2       0       WaterLevel centimeters
3 650 2017-02-05 19:55:44        3      12          Humidity     Percent
4 649 2017-02-05 19:55:43        4      25   AirTemperature     Celsius
```

I want to convert it so that sensor is the lookup key for the list and I can pull the reading out as the value. I would like the list to look like this when done.

```
$humidity
[1] "20%"

$airtemp
[1] "30 Degrees"

$waterlevel
[1] "0 cm"

$ watertemp
[1] "20 Degrees"
```

Comment: where is humidity and airtemp in this data?. the expected output doesn't seem to match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` divides the dataframe on each unique value of `sensor` and returns a list.

```
split(df, df$sensor)
```